# Size class for all iPhones but 6+

Tags: ios, iphone, size-classes

I want to make a distinct layout for all iPhones in landscape (wC/hC) and iPhone 6+ in landscape master VC (in split view controller). Is this possible?

Basically it's a table with rows. Each row represents a model instance. For wC/hC I want to show three labels side by side since there's enough space to horizontally lay out them and display the text data. I adjust their content hugging priority accordingly to truncate the least important one.

Now in iPhone 6+ I use the split view controller and the same VC that is used in all iPhones with three labels should have only two labels because it's too narrow to display all needed data. I've done adjusting the labels and constraints for these two size classes for over a few hours now - no luck.

Is it possible to have different layout for view controller in wC/hC and master view controller in wR/wC?

What is also funny that IB does not show the third label when I switch to wR/hC in editor and the master view controller is sized properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your intent correctly, in 6+ the third label should not be visible at all. To do that either:

1. Uninstall the label itself for the wRwC (6+)size class or,
2. Set a width (or height) constraint again only for that size class and use a constant of 0.

Picking one of the two depends on what you want to achieve. I generally tend to avoid the second one cause it feels "wrong / hackish" to me.

While making your decision, keep in mind that:

> A runtime object for an uninstalled view is still created. However, the view and any related constraints are not added to the view hierarchy and the view has a superview property of nil. This is different from being hidden. A hidden view is in the view hierarchy along as are any related constraints.

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableViews.html)

Comment: I have done the 1st option. The third label is not visible in the IB when in wRwC (I also checked the presence checkboxes for that size class), however it is displayed when running the app/